# Why are my SQL Server backup ending as a file that is twice the size of my database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 r2 database that is currently 56 GBs. When I run the following code I get a bak file that is 93 GBs. What could be causing this?

```
    BACKUP DATABASE [CommerceCenter]
TO DISK = 'N:\MSSQL\DATA\CC\CC_backup_tues.bak'
WITH COMPRESSION
```

If I use SSMS to run the backup to the same location with compression the bak file is only 8 GBs.

Comment: Have you written multiple backups to the same file? You haven't specified `WITH INIT` in your command. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, it's multiple backups inside the same file. To see it:

```
RESTORE HEADERONLY   
FROM DISK = N'N:\MSSQL\DATA\CC\CC_backup_tues.bak' ;
```

If you see multiple backups in there, you have a couple of different options:

- Specify a different file name per backup (I'm a huge fan of this - use date-based file names rather than days), or
- Use the WITH INIT command to overwrite the last backup - this can be a bad idea if you ever need to go back more than a week

Comment: Yes it had multiple files in it. For this database any backup over a week is useless, so I will go with the WITH INIT.  Thanks.